# Obj-C function declaration in header

Tags: objective-c, function

I am trying to put a C-style function in the header of an Objective-C class. (My terminology might be wrong here -- I'm just used to writing Objective-C class methods rather than functions). It looks as follows:

```
// Sort function
NSInteger sort(NSString *aString, NSString *bString, void *context);

NSInteger sort(NSString *aString, NSString *bString, void *context) {
    return [aString compare:bString options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Unforuntately this results in:

> Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '*attribute*' before '{' token

Any ideas as to what I'm missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that you put the function definition within the @interface of your class. Instead, make sure C style function declarations are outside of Objective-C @interface declarations:

```
// declare C functions here
NSInteger sort(NSString *aString, NSString *bString, void *context);

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
  // class instance vars
}

// class properties & instance methods
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring C-Styled methods you must forget about - or +. Just declare the method as an standard C one, before the `@end` statement:

`void function_name(int, int);`

Answer (score 2):

The body of your function needs to be in the .m file instead of in the header.

As long as the declaration of your function (`NSInteger sort(NSString *aString, NSString *bString, void *context);`) remains in the header you'll still be able to access the sort function from anywhere you import the header.